# Spring Batch and Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I am a junior programmer in banking. I want to make a microservice system that get data from kafka and processes it. after that, save to database and send final data to client app. What technology can i use? I plan to use spring bacth and kafka. Can the technology be implemented in my project or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process data from a Kafka topic I recommend you to use Kafka Streams API, especially Spring Kafka Streams.

- [Kafka Streams and Spring](http://%20https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kafka-streams)

And to store the data in a database, you should use a Kafka Sink Connector.

- [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html)

This approach is very common and easy if your company has a Kafka ecosystem.

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you. Can you explain what different use case between spring batch and kafka stream?

Comment: I  have never worked with the Spring batch, but I created some batch processes, the batch process is the way to process or retrieve data when you know when and how much data should process.  E.g   Your app is going to run every  4 hrs to consume data from a Kafka Topic and store that data in a database however a stream application is when you want to consume the data infinitely, your stream application always is running and waiting for data to process. Kafka is a streaming platform.  Wich should use? that depends on your current needed.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of alternatives, here you will find an interesting comparison:
https://scramjet.org/blog/welcome-to-the-family
[3 in 1 serverless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjtmT.png)

Scramjet takes a slightly different approach - 3 platforms in one.
Both the free product https://hub.scramjet.org/ for installation on your server and the cloud platform are available - currently also free in the beta version https://scramjet.org/#join-beta

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.